# How to stop listeners in SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I have 5 concurrentConsumers. How can I stop listening queue but let my consumers finish task (not republish message back to queue in the middle of the business logic) ?

If I call stop()/shutdown() method in SimpleMessageListenerContainer it waits for default 5 secconds and Forcing connections to close, and republishes messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug; the container should wait for inflight messages to complete but not start processing new ones. This is fixed - https://jira.springsource.org/browse/AMQP-338

Original [post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/amqp/724864-how-to-stop-listeners-in-simplemessagelistenercontainer)